# Why is the spirit of Anakin's young while Obi-Wan and Yoda's spirits are old?

Tags: star-wars, force-ghost

In the end of Star Wars Episode VI: Return of the Jedi, Anakin, Yoda and Obi-wan's spirits appear in a vision on Endor.

Obi-wan and Yoda look old (as they are when die), but Anakin is young.
[image]

Why is Anakin the only one to appear young if, when he died, he was old and deformed?